# Restoring paragraph breaks in text copied to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

A cell contains several paragraphs of text.

Some paragraph breaks are missing, causing two sentences to be squished together. Here's an example:

> Set in the moody off-season of Martha’s Vineyard, Everything That Follows is a plunge into the dark waters of secrets and flexible morals.The truth becomes whatever we say it is.

Is there away to restore the paragraph break for any sentences that are pressed together in this way?

Here's how I would like the text to be formatted:

> Set in the moody off-season of Martha’s Vineyard, Everything That Follows is a plunge into the dark waters of secrets and flexible morals.
>
> The truth becomes whatever we say it is.

I'm formatting over 100 cells like the one described above, so I'm hoping to find an alternative to manually inserting each line break. Please let me know if further info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually insert a line break.

To do this click into the cell, and ensure the blinker is where you want the line break, then press `ALT` + `ENTER`.

Also, you can do this as part of a string formatted with "" using `CHAR(10)`

Example `="First line of text"&CHAR(10)&"Second line of text"`

Will be displayed as:

```
First line of text
Second line of text
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I have more than one cell to format in this way - something I didn't make clear in my initial post. 

I usually have over 100 cells like the one mentioned above, that need to be formatted, so I'm hoping there's an alternative to manually inserting each line break.